# Como herdar de um ServerModule no DataSnap com Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou migrando uma aplicação Server com protocolo DCom e Borland Socket Sever em Delphi 2006 para **DataSnap** no **Delphi XE3**, porém na nova versão do DataSnap não estou conseguindo herdar um `ServerModule`.

Na parte visual, o `ServerModule` fica com a aparência de `vcl form`, quando passo uma herança ao invés de um `TDSServerModule`.

**Exemplo:**

```delphi
"TSMTeste = class(TSMHerança)"
```

Comment: Mas o que acontece? Não consegui entender sua pergunta...

Comment: Os componentes e rotinas que estão no "TDSServerModule Pai" não são disponibilizados / acessados pelo "TDSServerModule Filho" que herda do "TDSServerModule Pai", além disso a parte visual aparece como um form ao invés do module.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Você tem um TDS "template" e um TDS "filho", é isso? Se for, creio que você deva utilizar **published** no lugar do **public**. Dê uma olhada neste [link](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Public)

Comment: Valeu @EdgarMunizBerlinck pela atenção mais não seria isto, o problema é exemplo: no ServerModule Pai uso da seguinte forma 'TSMPai = class(TDSServerModule)' no ServerModule Filho passo herdando do Pai 'TSMFilho = class(TSMPai)', mais a parte visual '.dfm' fica como um Form ao invés de um Module..

Comment: @LeoBJr Como já está resolvido, marque a sua resposta como correta, para que ela possa ser tirada da lista de perguntas sem resposta, talvez ajustando o título para ajudar pessoas que tenham passado por um problema semelhante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido,

O problema era no .dpr e no .dproj, tinha que mudar a nomenclatura de TRemoteDataModule para TDSServerModule. 
Ai foi possível herdar um ServerModule.

Obrigado a todos,